# Front-end user cannot logout

Tags: ee2, members, logout

This is my first time using ExpressionEngine to allow users to log into the front end interface and see different content. The login aspect is working fine... but I can't seem to be able to log out!

Some details:

- EE 2.6
- CE Cache (using database caching, with the salient parts escaped, and turned off in the config file anyway as I'm not yet in production, so this should not be causing a conflict)
- Objective HTML's Authenticate plugin
- Security setting "User Session Type" set to "Cookies only". When setting it to "Session only" I cannot seem to log in at all!

I've tried using both `{exp:authenticate:logout}` and `{path='logout'}` (both rendering ?ACT=8, which I've confirmed in the database calls `Member` class method `member_logout`) but using either link does not seem to actually log the user out.

I've tried disabling the Authenticate extension and running the same ACT?ID=8, and though I get EE's "You are now logged out." screen, when I return I am stilled logged in and can still see logged in material.

Clearing local cache has no effect.

The only action that seems to get the user out is to go into my cookies and delete the `exp_sessionid` cookie.

Any suggestions/pointers/leads to follow are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be related to bug #19338 which was fixed in EE 2.6.1. There was also a manual fix that could be applied. See 19338 on the [changelog](http://userguides.ellislab.com/expressionengine/about/changelog.html).

Comment: Thanks! That could well be it. I'll give it a try later today and let everyone know.

Comment: I had a chance to try it and it did indeed resolve the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the user session type under Admin->Security and Privacy->Security and Sessions. I'm not sure which would be the best option so give all three a try!